# Three jquery coffeescript functions conflicting with one another

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I'm a relative amateur at coffeescript/javascript, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure it so that three different functions (two [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) functions and one function to load [Best in Place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place)) will work at the same time in a Rails 3 application. I have the following code in an asset pipeline file that's definitely getting loaded and converted to javascript, when the app runs:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#foo').select2()
        placeholder: "Choose an option.",
        allowClear: true
    $('#bar').select2()
        placeholder: "Choose an option.",
        allowClear: true
    $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

But when I put all three functions together like this, none of them work. When I run just one, like:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#foo').select2()
        placeholder: "Choose a diagnosis.",
        allowClear: true
```

Presto, that function works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This may be just a copy/paste error but looks like your indentation is wrong after the jQuery ->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your code doesn't really work at all, you might want to watch your JavaScript console when you try to run that code.

This:

```
$('#foo').select2()
    placeholder: "Choose an option.",
    allowClear: true
```

is the same as this JavaScript:

```
$('#foo').select2()({
    placeholder: "Choose an option.",
    allowClear: true
});
```

but you almost certainly want this JavaScript:

```
$('#foo').select2({
    placeholder: "Choose an option.",
    allowClear: true
});
```

To get that, your CoffeeScript would look like this:

```
$('#foo').select2
    placeholder: "Choose an option."
    allowClear: true
```

or like this:

```
$('#foo').select2(
    placeholder: "Choose an option."
    allowClear: true
)
```

This CoffeeScript:

```
$('#foo').select2()
    placeholder: "Choose an option.",
    allowClear: true
$('#bar').select2()
    placeholder: "Choose an option.",
    allowClear: true
$('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

should successfully execute `$('#foo').select2()` and then trigger a TypeError because `select2()` isn't returning a function but you're trying to call it like one. Then, the `$('#bar').select2()` and `$('.best_in_place').best_in_place()` won't even run.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem with the placeholders that was driving me nuts, too.

Comment: @Michael: I tend to use parentheses on my CoffeeScript function calls (especially multi-line ones) to avoid problems like this.